# How does the logistic regression with L-BFGS have to be initialized?

Tags: r, logistic, optimization

I've performed a logistic regression with L-BFGS on R and noticed that if I changed the initialization, the model retuned was different.

Here is my dataset (390 obs. of 14 variables, Y is the target variable) :

```
GEST    DILATE    EFFACE    CONSIS    CONTR    MEMBRAN    AGE    STRAT    GRAVID    PARIT    DIAB    TRANSF    GEMEL    Y
31           3       100         3        1         2     26         3         1        0       2         2       1     1
28           8         0         3        1         2     25         3         1        0       2         1       2     1
31           3       100         3        2         2     28         3         2        0       2         1       1     1
...
```

This dataset is found here: http://tutoriels-data-mining.blogspot.fr/2008/04/rgression-logistique-binaire.html in "Données : prematures.xls". Y is a column I created with the column "PREMATURE", Y=IF(PREMATURE="positif";1;0)

I've used the optimx package like here [Logistic regression with LBFGS solver](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/logistic-regression-with-lbfgs-solver), here is the code:

```
install.packages("optimx")
  library(optimx)

vY = as.matrix(premature['PREMATURE'])
# Recoding the response variable
vY = ifelse(vY == "positif", 1, 0)

mX = as.matrix(premature[c('GEST', 'DILATE', 'EFFACE', 'CONSIS', 'CONTR', 
                           'MEMBRAN', 'AGE', 'STRAT', 'GRAVID', 'PARIT', 
                           'DIAB', 'TRANSF', 'GEMEL')])

#add an intercept to the predictor variables
mX = cbind(rep(1, nrow(mX)), mX)

#the number of variables and observations
iK = ncol(mX)
iN = nrow(mX)

#define the logistic transformation
logit = function(mX, vBeta) {
  return(exp(mX %*% vBeta)/(1+ exp(mX %*% vBeta)) )
}

# stable parametrisation of the log-likelihood function
logLikelihoodLogitStable = function(vBeta, mX, vY) {
  return(-sum(
    vY*(mX %*% vBeta - log(1+exp(mX %*% vBeta)))
    + (1-vY)*(-log(1 + exp(mX %*% vBeta)))
  )  # sum
  )  # return 
}

# score function
likelihoodScore = function(vBeta, mX, vY) {
  return(t(mX) %*% (logit(mX, vBeta) - vY) )
}

# initial set of parameters (arbitrary starting parameters)
vBeta0 = c(10, -0.1, -0.3, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01)

optimLogitLBFGS = optimx(vBeta0, logLikelihoodLogitStable,
                         method = 'L-BFGS-B', gr = likelihoodScore, 
                         mX = mX, vY = vY, hessian=TRUE)
```

I get this :

```
 optimLogitLBFGS
                p1         p2       p3         p4         p5         p6
L-BFGS-B 9.720242 -0.1652943 0.525449 0.01681583 0.02781123 -0.3921004
                 p7          p8         p9       p10        p11        p12
L-BFGS-B -1.694412 -0.03461208 0.02759248 0.1993573 -0.6718275 0.02537887
                 p13      p14   value fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1  kkt2
L-BFGS-B -0.8374338 0.625044 187.581    121    121    NA        1 FALSE FALSE
          xtimes
L-BFGS-B  0.044
```

But if I change

```
vBeta0 = c(10, -0.1, -0.3, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
```

in

```
vBeta0 = rep(0.1, iK)
```

I get a different result :

```
optimLogitLBFGS
                 p1             p2             p3              p4               p5
L-BFGS-B 0.372672689046 0.206785276091 0.398104550108 0.0175008380158 -0.0460042719084
                 p6             p7               p8            p9            p10
L-BFGS-B 0.139760396213 -1.43192069477 -0.0207666651106 -1.1396642657 0.212186387416
                 p11             p12             p13            p14         value
L-BFGS-B -0.583698421298 0.0576485672766 -0.802789658686 0.993103617257 185.472518798
         fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1  kkt2 xtimes
L-BFGS-B    121    121    NA        1 FALSE FALSE   0.05
```

How can I choose the initial parameters to get the best model?

Comment: General advise would be: are there any variables that are constants, are factor variables declared as such, does parameter standardization help?

Comment: None of my variables are constant, but I have some variables in factor but i did not declare them as such because if I did I get an error....I did not even declared Y as factor because it returns an error. I don't know then if my model is correct.

Comment: Different initializations leads to different results in Logistic regression because of the method L-BFGS. It finds a local minima and it depends on the initialization. By increasing the sample size you can increase stability in cost space. So most of the initialization will lead to better minimas.

Comment: I'm working on Spark MLlib also where their is no initialization at all (see here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html) Do you know why?